# Android XML button layout, problems with shape width

Tags: android, layout, shapes, android-drawable, layer-list

I am trying to create an upper shadow for my button, but this does not take the full width of the bottom (see image below, shadow is in black inside the button).

How could I fix it?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

XML drawable (mybutton.xml)

```
<item>
    <layer-list>

         <item>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/white2"
                    android:endColor="@color/white"
                    android:angle="270" />
                <corners
                    android:radius="10dp" />
                <padding
                    android:left="10dp"
                    android:top="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"
                    android:bottom="10dp" />
             </shape>
         </item>

          <item 
              android:bottom="15dp" >
             <shape>
                <solid android:color="#000000"/>
                <corners
                    android:topLeftRadius="10dp" 
                    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
             </shape>
          </item>


    </layer-list>
</item>
```

XML LAYOUT

```
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:text="Info"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: post your xml code too

Comment: XML is already present!

Comment: Ah ok, posting it now!

Comment: Have you tried removing all the paddings and then add one by one to get the result you need?

Comment: Yes, the padding in the first shape affects the second shape as well... is this correct?

Removing paddings from the first shape solves my problem, but how could I keep the paddings too?